# Retrieve list of messages of two channels

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm currently developing a chat app in react native and firebase and I have created two channels, one for General chat and one for the Events. The problem is that when I send a message in the general channel, my list of messages of the events channel is replaced by the list of messages of the general channel. And if I send a message in the events channel, my list of messages of the general channel will be replaced by the list of messages of the events channel. How do you separate the discussions using firebase in order to avoid that conflict ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { loadMessages } from '../../../../store/chat/actions'
import { getChatItems } from '../../../../store/chat/selectors'

import MessageListComponent from './Component'

class MessagesListContainer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadMessages()
  }

  render() {
    const data = getChatItems(this.props.messages).reverse();
    console.log(this.data)
    return (
      <MessageListComponent
        data={data} />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  messages: state.chat.messages,
  error: state.chat.loadMessagesError
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loadMessages
}

MessagesListContainer.propTypes = {
  messages: PropTypes.object,
  error: PropTypes.string,
  loadMessages: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MessagesListContainer)
```

And that's my action.js where I link my General channel :

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'
import firebaseService from '../../services/firebase'

const FIREBASE_REF_MESSAGES = firebaseService.database().ref('Messages')
const FIREBASE_REF_MESSAGES_LIMIT = 20

export const sendMessage = message => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(chatMessageLoading())

    let currentUser = firebaseService.auth().currentUser
    let createdAt = new Date().getTime()
    let chatMessage = {
      text: message,
      createdAt: createdAt,
      user: {
        id: currentUser.uid,
        email: currentUser.email
      }
    }

    FIREBASE_REF_MESSAGES.push().set(chatMessage, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        dispatch(chatMessageError(error.message))
      } else {
        dispatch(chatMessageSuccess())
      }
    })
  }
}

export const updateMessage = text => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(chatUpdateMessage(text))
  }
}

export const loadMessages = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    FIREBASE_REF_MESSAGES.limitToLast(FIREBASE_REF_MESSAGES_LIMIT).on('value', (snapshot) => {
      dispatch(loadMessagesSuccess(snapshot.val()))
    }, (errorObject) => {
      dispatch(loadMessagesError(errorObject.message))
    })
  }
}


const chatMessageLoading = () => ({
  type: types.CHAT_MESSAGE_LOADING
})

const chatMessageSuccess = () => ({
  type: types.CHAT_MESSAGE_SUCCESS
})

const chatMessageError = error => ({
  type: types.CHAT_MESSAGE_ERROR,
  error
})

const chatUpdateMessage = text => ({
  type: types.CHAT_MESSAGE_UPDATE,
  text
})

const loadMessagesSuccess = messages => ({
  type: types.CHAT_LOAD_MESSAGES_SUCCESS,
  messages
})

const loadMessagesError = error => ({
  type: types.CHAT_LOAD_MESSAGES_ERROR,
  error
})
```

Thanks !

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant code and database structure, so we can understand what you're working with.

Comment: Perhaps you're holding over where you wrote the message to and using that to pull messages (when you switch channels)... we need more information to be more helpful

Comment: I've just edited the first message with some code ! I did the exact same code with the event channel with components and stuff